# Stormcrawler: Writing to a Elastic Cluster issue

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

**SC** when downloaded has a setup for *localhost ES*, which works perfectly with `--local` and `--remote`. When I change this to write to a Dev **Elastic Search server** (*cluster*) and I have updated, **ES_IndexInit.sh** and **es_conf.yaml** (**es.indexer.addresses** and **cluster.name**) to have the correct values for the properties. **ES_IndexInit** creates the indexes on that server just fine as expected, but this *never writes to that server*. I see *no errors* in the *logs* and I see the **URL** shows as *discovered* in the *logs*. This does not even write to the Status Index. I am not sure what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely a version conflict. The version 1.7 of the ES module depends [on ES 6.0.0](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/1.7/external/elasticsearch/pom.xml#L20) and 1.8 depends on 6.2.2.

I'd recommend that you use the latest version of StormCrawler available as it contains [numerous improvements and bugfixes](http://digitalpebble.blogspot.co.uk/2018/03/whats-new-in-stormcrawler-18.html).

Comment: Hi Julien, I won't be able to update the cluster version at this time. Would you be able to help with what version should I used for SC that matches to 5.6.3 ES?  Just one additional thing, with the same exact code, and localhost ES which is on 5.6.3, everything works perfectly fine, is there a difference?

Comment: Use the elasticsearch module version 1.6  https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/1.6/external/elasticsearch/pom.xml#L20

Comment: Thank you. I tried today and it seemed to work for Status, but when I run the es-crawler.flux command - i get this error: ERROR o.a.s.util - Async loop died! or Async loop interrupted! Can this be related? Do I have to modify the version of the storm-crawler-core, storm-core? or just storm-crawler-elasticsearch to 1.6?

Comment: And when I increase the sleep time for es-injector.flux command, it gets stucks at this line: INFO  c.d.s.e.p.StatusUpdaterBolt - Bulk response [1] : items 1, waitAck 0, acked 1

Answer (score 0):

Did you modify *es.status.addresses* and *es.metrics.addresses* as well?

Comment: Yes, all the three indexes have the correct values, for both the addresses and cluster name properties.

Comment: to add[forgot to mention this in my original question], it does write to the 'metrics' index, but not to 'status' and 'index'.

Comment: I have added an image for the ES log in the original question.

Comment: Looks like a version conflict between the client and the version of ES running on your cluster

Comment: I am using 5.6.3 on the cluster and the dependency in SC pom is as below: <dependency>
   <groupId>com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler</groupId>
   <artifactId>storm-crawler-elasticsearch</artifactId>
   <version>1.7</version>
  </dependency>, does version 1.7 have that version, afaik it does. Can you please confirm.